# Web Applications Security

Tags: security

Hi does anybody know of any other programs similar to Webgoat for the demonstration of web application security flaws?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of them. Some hosted, some for local installation. Some targeted more to teaching about web security, others for testing. Fortunately some folks already made some lists:

http://slogic.net/training/vulnerable-web-applications-to-learn-web-application-testing-skills

http://securitythoughts.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/vulnerable-web-applications-for-learning

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Phoenix/Tools#Testing_grounds

I personally would start with Google Gruyere (http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good list in here:
http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20090406/hacking-without-all-the-jailtime/

Answer (score 0):

The big ones I would think of would be Fortify and HP WebInspect.

Fortify will scan the source code and find potential vulnerabilities
HP WebInspect will scan/brute force a website in production and find/report actual vulnerabilities.

Both require a fairly expensive license.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [Codebashing](http://www.codebashing.com/sql_demo) - They are a SaaS based elearning platform that provide interactive application security wargames.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how the link works.

Comment: Im sorry - The link points to an interactive SQL injection exercise. Students can go through the exercise and attempt exploiting the issue, at the same time the interactive tutorial will teach them how the vulnerability occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`http://www.dvwa.co.uk/
 http://www.itsecgames.com/
 https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Bricks#tab=Main
 https://sourceforge.net/projects/mutillidae/`

Also I Like dawa And murillidae That is Realy Intresting.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at:

- [OWASP Testing Project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Testing_Project)
- [Acunetix Web Security Scanner](http://www.acunetix.com/)

> Acunetix WVS automatically checks your
>   web applications for SQL Injection,
>   XSS & other web vulnerabilities.